# How to dynamically create a Ruby method with paramers baked-in?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, module, metaprogramming

When creating a class method dynamically is there a way to bake-in some arguments known at the moment of creation?

I made a module for myself that is generating `:slug` attribute from given `:title` when I create models. https://gist.github.com/firedev/4943289

However I would want to refactor this part:

```
def create_slug(title_attr, slug_attr, &block) # generated method
  self.send(slug_attr) # I have to pass slug_attr from outside
  ...
end
```

So I can get rid of all the params here:

```
self.send :after_initialize do
  create_slug(title_attr, slug_attr, &block) # I pass attributes from here
end
```

And have parameters baked-in in the created method instead:

```
def create_slug # this method is generated automatically
  self.send(:slug) # I want :slug to be baked in 
  ...
end

self.send :after_initialize, :create_slug # no attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code: https://github.com/oleander/to_param-rb/blob/master/lib/to_param/base.rb

I think it does what you want.

**Usage:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  to_param :name
end

User.create(name: "Linus").to_param # => "1-linus"
```

Comment: Sorry, no, I store `slug` in database, I use it in `to_param` when needed. The question is if there is a way to bake attributes into method. I included the code to provide some background.

Comment: Please don't provide only a link to the code. *WHEN* the link breaks your answer will be nearly worthless. Instead, provide a summary of the linked code showing why it is correct, and then link to the full example.